# How to detect if any specific drive is a hard drive?

Tags: c#, hardware, hard-drive

In C# how do you detect is a specific drive is a Hard Drive, Network Drive, CDRom, or floppy?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The method GetDrives() returns a DriveInfo class which has a property DriveType that corresponds to the enumeration of System.IO.DriveType:

```
public enum DriveType
{
    Unknown,         // The type of drive is unknown.  
    NoRootDirectory, // The drive does not have a root directory.  
    Removable,       // The drive is a removable storage device, 
                     //    such as a floppy disk drive or a USB flash drive.  
    Fixed,           // The drive is a fixed disk.  
    Network,         // The drive is a network drive.  
    CDRom,           // The drive is an optical disc device, such as a CD 
                     // or DVD-ROM.  
    Ram              // The drive is a RAM disk.   
}
```

Here is a slightly adjusted example from MSDN that displays information for all drives:

```
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}, Type {1}", d.Name, d.DriveType);
    }
```

Comment: FYI `DriveType` returns `DriveType.Fixed' for external USB hard drives.

Answer (score 4):

[DriveInfo.DriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype.aspx) should work for you.

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("  File type: {0}", d.DriveType);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check [System.IO.DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) class and DriveType property.