# Detecting if disc is in DVD drive

Tags: c#

Is there an easy way to detect if a disc is inserted in the DVD drive? I don't care what kind of disc (CD, DVD or Blu-Ray)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148742/how-to-detect-if-any-specific-drive-is-a-hard-drive

Comment: There is an easy way to do find the answer you seek. It is called searching. On this very site alone there are a plethora of proposed solutions.

Comment: @Musa - That question isn't what I'm asking. That question is about detecting if a drive is a cdrom drive or a hard drive. Nothing to do with what I'm asking

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use WMI to detect if disk in CD/DVD drive:

```
foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                               .Where(d => d.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom))  
MessageBox.Show(drive.Name + " " + drive.IsReady.ToString());
```

from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/1ecb74cd-d193-40f5-9aa3-47a3c9adb4ea/).

[DriveType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can help you what kind of disc:

- `CDRom` : The drive is an optical disc device, such as a CD or DVD-ROM.
- `Fixed` : The drive is a fixed disk.
- `Network` : The drive is a network drive.
- `NoRootDirectory`    The drive does not have a root directory.
- `Ram` : The drive is a RAM disk.
- `Removable` : The drive is a removable storage device, such as a floppy disk drive or a USB flash drive.
- `Unknown` : The type of drive is unknown.

---

for kind of CD/DVD/Blue-Ray see [IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- UNKNOWN
- CDROM
- CDR
- CDRW
- DVDROM
- DVDRAM
- DVDPLUSR
- DVDPLUSRW
- DVDPLUSR_DUALLAYER
- DVDDASHR
- DVDDASHRW
- DVDDASHR_DUALLAYER
- DISK
- DVDPLUSRW_DUALLAYER
- HDDVDROM
- HDDVDR
- HDDVDRAM
- BDROM
- BDR
- BDRE
- MAX

your code may be like this:

```
public bool IsDiscAvailable(int driveNumber)
{
    MsftDiscMaster2Class discMaster = new MsftDiscMaster2Class();
    string id = discMaster[driveNumber];

    MsftDiscRecorder2Class recorder = new MsftDiscRecorder2Class();
    recorder.InitializeDiscRecorder(id);

    MsftDiscFormat2DataClass dataWriter = new MsftDiscFormat2DataClass();
    if (dataWriter.IsRecorderSupported(recorder))
    {
        dataWriter.Recorder = recorder;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Recorder not supported");
        return false;
    }
    if (dataWriter.IsCurrentMediaSupported(recorder))
    {
        var media = dataWriter.CurrentPhysicalMediaType;
        if (media == IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE.IMAPI_MEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown media or no disc");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found disc type {0}", media);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disc absent or invalid.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/4159cc0d-b517-40e2-9e8e-5b2a0c960359).

Answer (score 1):

[How to Detect CD-ROM is loaded in the CD-ROM drive](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/295010/How-to-Detect-CD-ROM-is-loaded-in-the-CD-ROM-drive)

From above link

```
using System;
using System.Management;

class Application
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SelectQuery query = 
            new SelectQuery( "select * from win32_logicaldisk where drivetype=5" );
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        foreach( ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get() )
        {
            // If both properties are null I suppose there's no CD
            if(( mo["volumename"] != null) || (mo["volumeserialnumber"] != null))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CD is named: {0}", mo["volumename"]);
                Console.WriteLine("CD Serial Number: {0}", mo["volumeserialnumber"]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No CD in Unit");
            }
        }

        // Here to stop app from closing
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress Return to exit.");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because links expire, simply providing a link does not constitute a good answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Comment: you are right, but when a thing already exits why not we reuse it

Comment: I have posted the code now, then there is no need to vote down.

Comment: Yeah, down voters are dumb. (also because they lose reputation as well) I'll help you up to 0.