# Can I store a program on a USB Ethernet/WIFI adapter?

Tags: ethernet, usb-drive

Can I store a program on a USB Ethernet/WIFI adapter and auto-run the program when the usb wifi adapter is plugged in? Is it scenario where it may be possible on some but not other USB wifi adapters?

Rees-pek!

Comment: probably, but since you haven't mentioned any particular brand/model, we can't help you more than that.

Comment: It would be nice if you would go ahead and suggest some brands which would have this capability. Eventually, I would need non-branded ones with this capability so I can put lil stickers of my program's name on em. But you answered my question, it was a yes or no question. So...REES-PEK!

Comment: That is NOT what this site is about. We are not here to google for products for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.
However, most of the Huawei 3G/4G devices have a virtual CD-ROM drive built-in.
And yes, you can modify the firmware to run your own code (It's an ISO image).
On a regular WiFi USB adapter, best chance would be to add an USB hub chip and a Arduino Teensy to send commands, yet, would be very big to fit in the original casing.
Or, just plant some regular USB flash drive inside the USB Wifi plastic casing.
Out of curiosity, why would you want this ?

Comment: The mac address of a portable usb wifi adapter is essential to my program. Ill explore more into that virtual cd-rom. THANKS!

Comment: Some Huwaei models have both 3G and Wifi, maybe that's an option ?

Comment: Or, if you just need to read the MAC and validate against a whitelist, there's plenty of code to do it. There's no need to run the code in the adapter itself.

Comment: I want to distribute my program on a usb drive, so what better than the adapter itself right? I want to lock the usb so the program cannot be accessed to be read or written, only executed. this feature is for the protection of the program, not for the purpose ofprotection source code.

Comment: In what language are you trying to acomplish this?
Just asking because if it is C#, go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148742/how-to-detect-if-any-specific-drive-is-a-hard-drive